# Django different timezones in same application

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I am working on a Django application on Leave Management, in which there are employees from different countries. I am storing the data of the time, when the leave is created, into DB. Now, I want this datetime that is being inserted into DB, to be the current local time of the location where that particular employee is working at.

For example, let us suppose Mr. X is working at India and Y is working at Newyork. If X applies for a leave, I want it to be created at local time (created_at= *what-so-ever time it is in India*) and when Y applies for a leave, I want it to be created_at=*what-so-ever time it is in Newyork*. As of now, whatever I am inserting into DB, it is getting inserted as UTC time only. How to resolve this issue?

I am trying to achieve something like this.. But it is always UTC.

```
userid = employees.objects.get(emp_id=request.user.username)

if employees.objects.get(emp_id=request.user.username).emp_loc == 'IND':
    tzone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
elif employees.objects.get(emp_id=request.user.username).emp_loc == 'MLA':
    tzone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Manila')
elif employees.objects.get(emp_id=request.user.username).emp_loc == 'MPLS':
    tzone=pytz.timezone('CST6CDT')

 timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzone))
 tnow=timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

if request.POST['action'] == 'Save changes':
        new_leave = leave.objects.create(employee=employees.objects.get(emp_id = userid.emp_id), start_date=sdt, end_date=edt, ltype=ltyp, message=des, date_created=tnow)

    new_leave.save()
```

Badly in need of help..... :(

Thanks in advance......... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

You can set timezone to your datetime before saving it to database.
go to your settings.py and se USE_TZ to False

> Please read Update 3 section.

```
    import pytz
    from datetime import datatime

    leave = leave.objects.get(pk=1)
    time_zone = pytz.timezone('America/Bogota') # set timezone here

    # Before save
    leave.start_date = time_zone.localize(datetime.now())
    leave.save()
    leave.start_date
    > datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17, 11, 50, 25, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Bogota' -05-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
      # when USE_TZ is False
```

Or you can store timezone of employee in your leave model and convert it on time of retrieval manually.

```
import pytz

leave = leave.objects.get(pk=1)
time_zone = pytz.timezone(leave.timezone) # set timezone here

# OR on retrieval
leave_start_date = time_zone.localize(leave.start_date) # timezone aware datetime
```

**UPDATE**

The PostgreSQL backend stores datetimes as timestamp with time zone. In practice, this means it converts datetimes from the connection’s time zone to UTC on storage, and from UTC to the connection’s time zone on retrieval.

> for more info you can check the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ), under
>   **Migration guide** section.

**UPDATE 2**

It doesn't matter if you are using postgresql, if want to save multiple timezone you must set [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) = False,

then follow the steps above and get the datetime in the local time zone

> PS: This is not Best Practice see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/zwQju7hbG78

**UPDATE 3**

> The previous approaches, although they clarify but are not recommended

1. keep USE_TZ=True(if your django version supports it)
2. rename created_at DateTimeField to utc_created_at

```
    utc_created_at = models.DateTimeField(.....)
```

3. extend your django model by adding 3 additional fields:

   - a DateField local_created_at
   - a TimeField local_created_time
   - a CharField created_timezone(whatever it is fine)

```
local_created_date = models.DateField(blank=True, .....)
local_created_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, .....)
local_timezone = models.models.CharField(verbose_name="time zone", default=settings.TIME_ZONE, max_length=40)
```

4. override model save() - (it is just an example, check the best way to do this)

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    dt = self.utc_created_at
    if dt:
        self.local_created_date = dt.date()
        self.local_create_time = dt.time()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

5. In your form (be sure to use this form in admin.py)

```
import pytz
TIME_ZONE_CHOICES = [
    (timezone, timezone) for timezone in pytz.common_timezones
]
timezone = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TIME_ZONE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: But I want it to be stored in the database itself. Isn't there any possible way?

Comment: yes you can do, i have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but, still UTC time is being stored in DB :/

Comment: In database it will always be in UTC with timezone info, but when you show it in your templates it will  auto translates to user's timezone.

Comment: No way to store non-UTC in DB?

Comment: if you are using PostgreSQL it is not possible, check my update section and read official docs.