# Talk about the timezone in the Django when store in the MySQL database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created those data by the API of my Django/Django-Rest-Framework project. I using MySQL database.

but there is a issue, in the database, the timezone is `UTC`, and my timezone is +8(Beijing Time) timezone.

but when I query out the data, it still is the UTC time.

How to standardizing this timezone?

I surmise there are two way to do that,

1. when store the data, timezone set to the +8.
2. when query out the data, the time convert to +8 timezone.

But both I don't know how to realize, who can tell me what's your best solution?

---

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my configurations in `settings.py` are bellow:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-cn'  

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django different timezones in same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135190/django-different-timezones-in-same-application)

Comment: If you’re using PostgreSQL, do  `USE_TZ = False` so that database connection’s time zone will be set to TIME_ZONE, You don’t need to perform any data conversions. [read official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#migration-guide)